# How to stop a python script launching many subprocesses from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I have a python script which launches a sequence of subprocesses in a loop:

```
for c in cmds:
  subprocess.call(c, shell=True)
```

When the script is running in terminal, I try to stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, however, it will continue to launch next subprocess. How can I terminate the whole python script at once?

Comment: I think this is a function of your OS and development environment (if any).  What are you using for a platform?

Comment: Did you try `kill -9`?

Comment: Linux (CentOS). Yes, finally I killed it with `kill -9`.

Comment: ctrl + z will also work for this typically.

Comment: Note that ctrl + z (most flavors of Linux) puts the process in the background. The process will continue to create subprocesses. Probably not what the OP needed.

Comment: Regarding CTRL-Z - it does not put process in the background, it stops it by sending STOP signal. Stopping is different from killing, stopped process is suspended (not running), you can send it to background by using `bg` command, or you can restart it in foreground with `fg`.

Answer (score 0):

What likely happens is that ctrl-C is intercepted by you sub-process (running on the same terminal) and never gets to your Python script. What you can do is to check the return value of `subprocess.call` to see whether the child process was killed by a signal and decide whether you want to stop submitting new processes.